# How to serial(or distinguish) function parameter or serial a function call result in python elegantly?

Tags: python

I need serial some function results.

Now, my solution is using `pickle` package, and a decorator called `@serial_result`:

```py
def serial_result(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        dump_fname = func.__name__ + ('.' + str(args) if args else '') + ('.' + str(kwargs) if kwargs else '') + '.dump'
        serial_file = SERIAL_FILE_DIR + dump_fname
        if os.path.exists(serial_file):
            print('[serial_result] is loading results of function %s ...' % (func.__name__,))
            return pickle.load(open(serial_file, 'rb'))
        else:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('[serial_result] is dumping results of function %s ...' % (func.__name__,))
            pickle.dump(result, open(serial_file, 'wb'))
            return result

    return wrapper
```

```py
@serial_result
def get(type):
    pass
```

The decorator first check if the dump file exists. If so, deserialize and return. Or call the function, serialize the result and write to file.

The first version of the decorator just use `func.__name__` as the serial file name, one function use one same dump file.
But I want to **make the decorator identify different parameter passed to the function**
since `get(0)` and `get(1)` may return different result.
Now I just use `str(args)` and `str(kwargs)` as dump file name.
I think this approach may break sooner or later: special characters, object memory address, so on.

Here comes the question:
The decorator must distinguish different parameters passed.
Any other ideas to do this more elegant and pythonic?

Comment: Do you ever expect to get arguments that do not have a string representation? Also, do you ever expect to get arguments that are not hashable? As your decorator is now, I believe it would not work as expected if one of the arguments does not implement `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Comment: As an aside, you should decorate `wrapper` with `@functools.wraps(func)`.